# arduino sql + rgb лента

Tags: mysql, sql, arduino

Стоит задача на ардуинке собрать такую вещь, которая будет отображать обмен с бд в mysql , то есть обмен идёт между бд, диоды на ленте светятся зеленым, обмен встал, определенный диод светится красным.

Час гугления не дал норм уроков с чего начать именно самый низкий порог вхождения, большая часть идёт "1-что такое ардуино. 2 установка ИДЕ. 3 УМНЫЙ ДОМ НА АРДУИНО" ) Прошу подскажите с чего и какаких библиотек начать ?

Comment: Чтото я не понял, нужно чтоли на Ардуине поднять базу данных MySQL??

Comment: Или база крутиться на нормальном ПК, а ардуина подключена к этому ПК и служит только для управления лентой?

Comment: Декомпозируйте вашу задачу на части. Сейчас она звучит как "Как построить дом с фонарем?"

Comment: @StorozhevDJ да, ардуина только для отображения и управления лентой, насколько я понимаю, будет приходить сигнал об остановке работы обмена sql и следственно нужный диод будет светить красным, если сигнала нет, то светит зеленым

Comment: Кто и как будет посылать сигнал об остановке?
Как ардуина его получит?

Answer (score 1):

Для мониторинга работы MySQL можно воспользоваться утилитой mytop, вывод с которой перенаправить в виртаульный COM порт таким образом

> mytop [arguments] > /dev/ttyUSB0

Данные через виртуальный COM порт будут переданы на ардуино, там разобраны и включен соответствующий светодиод.
Либо, как более оптимальный вариант будет написать Bash скрипт, который будет разбирать вывод от mytop и посылать на Ардуино только команды какой светодиод включить.
Как принять данные по СОМ порту и включить светодиод можно посмотреть 
в статье http://www.customelectronics.ru/arduino-rabota-s-com-portom/
Так же не забываем про более релевантный ресурс https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions